# Xamarin Forms CocosSharp pause / resume scene android not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cocos2d-x, cocossharp

in Xamarin Forms i've added a CocosSharpView with a simple animation

```
  CCMoveTo myactions = new CCMoveTo(1f, new CCPoint(100, 100));
  CCMoveTo myactions2 = new CCMoveTo(4f, new CCPoint(0, 100));
  CCMoveTo myactions3 = new CCMoveTo(2f, new CCPoint(0, 0));
  CCMoveTo myactions4 = new CCMoveTo(2f, new CCPoint(100, 0));

  CCSequence seq = new CCSequence(myactions, myactions2, myactions3, myactions4);
   circle.AddAction(seq);
```

i want to pause / resume the Scene by clicking a button.

```
Director.RunningScene.Pause();
Director.RunningScene.Resume();
```

i found that there was a bug in Cocos2d and android. i'm not sure if i'm doing something wrong or this is still a bug?

i just need a way to pause / resume the sequence

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside the scene, maybe this.Pause() will do the trick.